# Do holomorphic bijections map contours enclosing the origin (winding number $1$) to contours enclosing the origin (with winding number $1$)?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, contour-integration

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\g}{\gamma}$So I was recently reviewing the proof of Lagrange-Burmann inversion:

> Consider functions of the form $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C,\,w\mapsto w/\psi(w)$ where $\psi:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of the origin and of non-zero constant term. All such $f$ admit an holomorphic local inverse $g$, defined in some neighbourhood of the origin, with power series: $$[z^n]g(z)=\frac{1}{n}[w^{n-1}]\psi(w)^n,\quad n\in\Bbb N$$

The proof is delightfully short using contour integration, however I have a small quibble about the images of contours under holomorphic maps.

> By the inverse function theorem is $g$ well-defined and analytic in some neighbourhood of the origin; let $\gamma$ be an anticlockwise closed contour enclosing a simply connected neighbourhood of the origin, with winding number $1$, contained within the domain of $g$. By Cauchy: $$\begin{align}[z^n]g(z)=&\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{g(z)}{z^{n+1}}\d z\\\overset{z=f(w)}{=}&\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\color{blue}{g(\gamma)}}\frac{w}{w^{n+1}}\cdot\psi(w)^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{\psi(w)}-w\cdot\frac{\psi'(w)}{\psi(w)^2}\right)\d w\end{align}$$

And so on - the proof follows easily from there, reliant on the key assumption that: $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\color{blue}{g(\gamma)}}\frac{\psi(w)^n}{w^n}\d w=[w^{n-1}]\psi(w)^n$$This formula is valid if $g(\gamma)$ is a closed contour, of winding number $1$, enclosing some simply connected neighbourhood of the origin in which $\psi$ is holomorphic. $g$ must be injective, so I can assure myself that the path $g(\gamma)$ is indeed closed and does not intersect itself (although, is that sufficient to say that the winding number is $1$? My geometry is hazy) but I cannot assure myself $g(\gamma)$ encloses the origin. Yes, $\gamma$ enclosed the origin and $g(0)=0$, but $g$ mapping the neighbourhood enclosed by $\gamma$ to some other neighbourhood of the origin is not the same, I think, as *the path* $g(\gamma)$ enclosing the origin, or enclosing this neighbourhood.

Maybe by homotopy invariance we can argue $g(\gamma)$ is homotopic to a suitable Cauchy-formula contour, but I don't see how this can be argued. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The winding number of $\Gamma = g \circ \gamma$ with respect to the origin is
$$
I(\Gamma, 0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\Gamma \frac 1w \, dw
= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)} \, dz = \operatorname{Res}(\frac{g'}{g}, 0) = 1
$$
according to the Residue theorem, and because the only singularity of $g'/g$ is a simple pole at the origin, with residue equal to one.

Comment: Ah - and that the result is $1$ is in turn a proof that it encloses the origin as well, right? Since $\gamma$ was taken small enough that $g$ is not zero anywhere else